# Creating PHP Search Page to search SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, sqlsrv

**Edited for more info

I'm having issues creating a search page to display results from a SQL Server database.  My SQL is correct because it outputs what I want in SSMS.  My connection info is also correct as I've tested that.  My issue is coming from tying it into the search form - I can't get it to find any results.  If I want it to print a table it prints just fine, however, I really need this to work as a search.  I'm still pretty new at PHP and SQL in general but this is what I have so far:

```
$serverName = "myserver";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydb", "UID"=>"myuser", "PWD"=>"mypass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo) OR die ('broke:' .sqlsrv_errors());
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT columns_I_need 
                                  FROM tables_I_need
                                  WHERE col_1 LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die('broke:' .sqlsrv_errors()); 
$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);

if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was nothing';
    } else {
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
            $stname = $row['streetname'];
            $stno = $row['streetnumber'];
            $apno = $row['permitnumber'];

            $output .= '<div> '.$stname.' '.$stno.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

My search form looks like this:

```
<form>  action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for address...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php print("$output"); ?>
```

Every time I search I get no results.  So I guess my question is: is my search form correct and is my `WHERE col_1 LIKE '%$searchq%'` correct?  What am I missing?  Also, does the `preg_replace` not help in preventing sql injection?

If this isn't descriptive enough, please let me know.

Comment: what exactly is going wrong? You've said there are issues but not said what the issues are. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection - research the use of parameterised queries / prepared statements.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: Long day yesterday, sorry for leaving that out.  When I search it doesn't find any results.  I just get There was nothing based on the $output.  Would it be better to dump the db into an XML file and then search the file to prevent any security risks?

Comment: I wouldn't dump your DB to XML. The performance will be terrible. You just need to re-write your query using a parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to do with this line:

```
$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
```

From the documentation for `sqlsrv_num_rows()` on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) (emphasis mine).

> **Parameters**
>   The statement for which the row count is returned. **The statment resource must be created with a static or keyset cursor**.
>
> <sup>Parameters - sqlsrv_num_rows</sup>

and

> **Return Values**
>   Returns the number of rows retrieved on success and FALSE if an error occurred. **If a forward cursor (the default) or dynamic cursor is used, FALSE is returned.**
>
> <sup>Return Values - sqlsrv_num_rows</sup>

Because you have failed to specify a cursor in your query, the default cursor is used and `false` is returned, regardless if the query had returned results.

Then in your `if` statement, you check `$count == 0`. This check will return `true`, as `0` can be evaluated to `false` and you are not using strict type comparison (`===`). Therefore you will always see "There was nothing".

To fix this, you will need to specify a *static* or *keyset* cursor for your query. I'm going to use `SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC` as my cursor as an example, but you could use `SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET`. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver) for more information about the different cursors.

The general syntax is:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC));
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'll do some more reading on parameterized queries and report back!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this nailed down.  It displays everything I need, I *believe* it's set up as a parameterized query, and with my class tags I'm able to style the output.

My only issue is if someone enters the street number AND the street name or the street name is two or more words, I don't get any results.  It's probably something simple with my `$sql` statement.  I tried:

`WHERE (STNO LIKE '%$search_term%' AND STNAME LIKE '%$search_term%') OR  APNO LIKE '%$search_term%'`

but that doesn't get me anything either.

```
$serverName = "myserver";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydb", "UID"=>"myuser", 
"PWD"=>"mypass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo) OR die ('broke:' 
.sqlsrv_errors());

$search_term = $_GET['query'];

$sql = "SELECT my rows FROM my tables
WHERE STNO LIKE '%$search_term%' OR STNAME LIKE '%$search_term%' OR APNO LIKE '%$search_term%'
ORDER BY STNO";

echo "<div class='search-term-display'>You searched for: ", $search_term, "</div>";

if(isset($_GET['query']))   {
    $search_term = $_POST['query'];
    $search_term = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $search_term);
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => 'static'));

while($data = sqlsrv_fetch($query)) {
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
            $stno = $row['STNO'];
            $stname = $row['STNAME'];
            $apno = $row['APNO'];
            $suffix = $row['SUFFIX'];
            $hseptyp = $row['HSEPTYP'];
            $dttm = $row['COMPDTTM']->format('d/m/Y');
            $partial = $row['PARTIAL'];
            $waived = $row['WAVIED'];
            $failed = $row['FAILED'];
            $inspcomments = $row['INSPECTIONCOMMENTS'];
            $fcomments = $row['FAILEDCOMMENTS'];
            $descript = $row['DESCRIPT'];

            echo "<hr>";
            echo "<div class='insp_address'>".$stno.' '.$stname.' Permit Number: '.$apno."</div>";
            echo "<div class='insp_date'>".'Inspection Date: '.$dttm."</div>";
            echo "<div class='sys_type'>".'Septic System Type: ' .$hseptyp."</div>";
            echo "<div class='code_violation_status'>".'Code Violation Status: ' .$descript."</div>";
            echo "<div class='code_violation'>".'Code: '.$failed."</div>";
            echo "<div class='insp_comments_title'>Inspection Comments:</div>";
            echo "<div class='insp_comments'>".$fcomments."</div>";
    }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $query);

    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used the query and fetch with keyset:

```
$this->result = SQLSRV_QUERY($this->conn, $this->sql, Array(), Array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
        SQLSRV_FETCH($this->result,SQLSRV_SCROLL_RELATIVE,$this->offset);

        for($row = 1; $row <= $this->items_per_page; $row++) {
            $rows[] = SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY($this->result);
        }
        return $rows;
```

Then you can use foreach like this:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $rows) {
            if ($rows != NULL) { ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['TerritoryID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['TerritoryDescription']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['RegionID']?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
```

Forgot to add a good rowcount block:

```
Function get_total_rows() {
            $row_count = SQLSRV_QUERY($this->conn, $this->sql, Array(), Array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
            return SQLSRV_NUM_ROWS($row_count);
            SQLSRV_FREE_STMT($row_count);
        }
```